# Git: Undoing all until the beginning of branch

Tags: git, github

Okay, I messed up and committed and pushed my changes to a branch that is supposed to serve as the clean master branch called `release/2.0`. So I committed and pushed and merged everything to this master branch.

Instead I am supposed to create a branch off of `release/2.0` and put all my work in that and commit and push and merge to `release2.0`.

How do I accomplish this? This is my `git reflog --date=iso`:

```
    22a3aed (HEAD -> member_benefits_config, origin/release/2.0, release/2.0) HEAD@{2019-07-08 13:50:12 -0500}: checkout: moving from release/2.0 to member_benefits_config
22a3aed (HEAD -> member_benefits_config, origin/release/2.0, release/2.0) HEAD@{2019-07-08 13:36:51 -0500}: pull origin release/2.0: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
2da8de0 HEAD@{2019-07-08 13:35:28 -0500}: commit: Added MemberBenefits configuration
4652cf5 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) HEAD@{2019-07-08 13:32:22 -0500}: checkout: moving from master to release/2.0
4652cf5 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) HEAD@{2019-07-08 13:32:10 -0500}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
8bd42a0 HEAD@{2019-07-08 13:01:19 -0500}: commit: Added MemberBenefits step component
4652cf5 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) HEAD@{2019-07-01 11:24:26 -0500}: clone: from https://CortesD@bitbucket.nfib.org/scm/enga/engage-application.framework.git
```

Would I be doing a `git reset --hard 22a3aed` on the "master" branch? Or the `4652cf5` commit where I had to do a reset because of my first screw up.

Comment: First of all, create the branch with the changes you inserted by mistake, then hard reset the "master" branch to the commit that's before yours.

Comment: Create new branch from the HEAD of the branch you messed up. This will be your backup. Now go back to relase branch. Reset hard to last commit you want. And force push it.
Now go back to your backup branch and push it under the name you want instead of release 2.0

Comment: @Maroun, could you take another look at my post? I updated it.

Comment: @TomasBruckner, `release/2.0` is my "master" branch. So far I just basically did a `git checkout -b member_benefits_config` which is the branch I want to commit and push and merge my work from. I am unsure which commit I want to reset back to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following commits on `release/2.0`:

```
17f4e3b87 commit 5
b5fdf57ab commit 4
ad53f1aa0 commit 3
3b6864d4d commit 2
88b87878d commit 1
```

Assuming that "commit 2" is the commit you want to get back to. You can do the following:

```
# create a branch and push changes to it
(release/2.0) git checkout -b my_branch
(my_branch) git push origin my_branch
```

Now reset the `release/2.0` to one commit before you introduce the changes:

```
git checkout release/2.0
git reset --hard 3b6864d4d
git push origin releases/2.0 -f
```